# webpack-hot reload - CSS stylesheet doesnt update

Tags: css, webpack

This is my below express setup

```
 if(process.env.NODE_ENV.trim()==='development'){

    app.use(webpackDevMiddleware(compiler, {
      publicPath: config.output.publicPath,
      stats: {colors: true}
    }))

    app.use(webpackHotMiddleware(compiler, {
      log: console.log
    })) 

  }
```

webpack.config

```
module.exports = {
  entry:[
    'webpack/hot/dev-server',
    'webpack-hot-middleware/client?http://0.0.0.0:8080&reload=true',
    './client/index.js'
  ],
  output:{
    path:__dirname + '/public',
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module:{
    rules:[
      {
        test:/(\.js|\.jsx)$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,

        use: [
          {
            loader: 'react-hot-loader'
          },
          {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
          }
        ]
      },
      { test: /\.json$/, loader: 'json-loader' },
      {
        test: /(\.css|\.scss)$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({fallback: 'style-loader',loader: extract_loaders})
      },
      {
        test   : /\.(ttf|eot|svg|woff(2)?)(\?[a-z0-9=&.]+)?$/,
        loader : 'file-loader'
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve:{
    extensions:['.js', '.jsx']
  },
  plugins:[
    new ExtractTextPlugin({filename: 'style.css', allChunks: true}),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
      {from: 'client/images' ,to: 'public/images'}
    ]),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({ options: { postcss: [ autoprefixer ] } })
  ],
}
```

When i update my jsx files - the site seems to update. But the hot update doesnt happen when i change my css files

webpack seems to compile properly though when css is changed. but for some reasons , the new `style.css` file isnt seen in the browser.

if it'll be of any help .. i'm importing the style.css file from my HTML file

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style.css">`

**update:** when i change my css file , i get the below messages in my console

```
[HMR] Checking for updates on the server...
[HMR] Nothing hot updated
```

this doesnt appear when i change `.jsx`

Comment: Did you find a solution @Kunkka?

Comment: @Kevin - no :( .. just manual refreshing now

Answer (score 3):

Just don't use ExtractTextPlugin in development webpack configuration, because it extracts your styles to separate file, so HMR can't do nothing with it. Fast fix:

```
       {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader'
            // use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
            //     fallback: "style-loader",
            //     use: "css-loader!sass-loader",
            // })
       }
```

Comment: +1 Looks like MiniCssExtractPlugin messed up the things to me. When I removed from development mode everything started to working consistently.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have babel and webpack you can just import your css files in code files.

Example:

```
import 'styles.css';
```

It would be then bundled and loading should work.

Comment: I unfortunately cannot include this statement in my client files because i'm rendering the page server-side. this require statement throws an error when compiling on the server side.

Comment: Hey check this article: https://medium.com/@justinjung04/react-server-side-rendering-and-hot-reloading-ffb87ca81a89#.o9z8kyb9s

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the issue is with the import line?
Have you tried it without the backslash? (assuming it's in the same directory)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
```